# Count specific number in Foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, count

How many times a specific number appear inside foreach loop.

For this i have try array_count_values function but it return total with above value in foreach loop.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($users as $user_id){ ?>
  <tr>
     <td><?php echo $id = $user_id->ID; ?></td>

  <?php $user_results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "mlw_results WHERE deleted='0' AND  (user=%d OR email='%s')", $id, $email) ); ?>

   <?php foreach( $user_results as $result ) { ?>
      <td><?php echo  $result->correct_score.', ';?></td>
   <?php } ?>

  </tr>  
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Current Output:-

```
   UserID                 Number

        1                 33, 55, 88, 100, 66, 4

        2                 33, 77, 88, 100, 100, 4

        3                 22, 51, 80, 100, 100, 4

        4                 1, 48, 56, 15, 78, 65, 45
```

Expected Output:-

```
   UserID                 Number

       1                  100 comes 1 time.

       2                  100 comes 2 time.

       3                  100 comes 2 time.

       4                  100 comes 0 time.
```

Comment: I don't see where you tried `array_count_values`. Is it only 100 that needs to be counted?

Comment: Yes, i want only 100 value counted.

I try array_count_values but it gives total count with above value.  like: "100 comes 1 time", "100 comes 3 time", "100 comes 5 time", "100 comes 5 times"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter a counter and place an if for cases that are equal to 100, Example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($users as $user_id){ ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $id = $user_id->ID; ?></td>

      <?php

        $user_results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "mlw_results WHERE deleted='0' AND  (user=%d OR email='%s')", $id, $email) );

        $count=0;

        foreach( $user_results as $result ) { 
          if($result->correct_score===100){
            $count++;
          }
        }
      ?>
      
      <td><?php echo '100 comes '.$count.' time.';?></td>
    </tr>  
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, for sharing this code, it's work. It's a great code just change "===" to "==" in there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your array and foreach then you should be able to use array_count_values since it returns an associative array.

Replace your second foreach with:

```
$counts = array_count_values($user_results->correct_score);
echo "100 comes ";
if(isset($counts[100])){
    echo $counts[100];
}else{
    echo "0";
}
echo " times";
```

Comment: Not working it showing "100 comes 0 times" in every row.

Comment: Can you post the $user_results array in your question so that I can see it?

Comment: And `$counts["100"]`?

Comment: @kuh-chan `$counts["100"]` is the same as `$counts[100]`. So what are you try to say?

Answer (score 0):

> Code:

```
<?php

$data = [
    1 => [33, 55, 88, 100, 66, 4],
    2 => [33, 77, 88, 100, 100, 4],
    3 => [22, 51, 80, 100, 100, 4],
    4 => [1, 48, 56, 15, 78, 65, 45]
];


function printOccurence(array $data, $neddle)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $dat) {

        if (in_array($neddle, $dat)) {
            echo "$key comes $neddle " . array_count_values($dat)[$neddle] . " times." . PHP_EOL;

        } else {
            echo "$key comes $neddle " . "0" . " times." . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

printOccurence($data, 100);
```

> Usage:

```
printOccurence($data, 100);
```

> Result:

```
1 comes 100 1 times.
2 comes 100 2 times.
3 comes 100 2 times.
4 comes 100 0 times.
```

Comment: You forgot the `Notice: Undefined offset: 100` as output in the fourth case

Comment: That works... Why do you int cast the result from array_count_values when you concatenate it in a string? The value is string in the array (if I recall correctly) you int cast it, then concatenate it to string again. Edit: nope. It's integers in the array.

Comment: @Andreas Because I had an empty string (not "0") - number in fourth example before I used if-else and did everything in one line due to lack of checking `in_array()`

Comment: @Andreas the value coming form `array_count_values` is an array `key => (int) number`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this https://3v4l.org/v70jC

```
$numbers = [
    [33, 55, 88, 100, 66 ,4],
    [33, 77, 88, 100, 100, 4],
    [22, 51, 80, 100, 100, 4],
    [1, 48, 56, 15, 78, 65, 45 ]
];

foreach ($numbers as $row) {
    if (in_array(100, $row)) {
        $amountOfHundreds = array_count_values($row)[100];
        echo $amountOfHundreds . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```